# Sorting many data frames in a directory

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

In a directory, say`"c/Mydata"`, I have 100 data frames named `d1, d2, d3, ..., d100`. The data frames are in text format saved with the extension `.dat`. Each data frame consists of the same number and name of variables; one of these variables being `id`. Using R, I want to sort each data frame by id and save the sorted data frames in the same directory. That is,

```
setwd("c/Mydata") # setting a working directory take each data frame: d1, d2, d3, ..., d100;
sorted1 = d1[order(d1$id),], sorted2 = d2[order(d2$id),], ..., sorted100 = d100[order(d100$id),] #order each data frame by id
# write the sorted data frames in the same directory - "c/Mydata"
```

Each data frame consisting of 12000 observations and more than 50 variables. The following can be taken to sample data frames:

```
d1 = data.frame(id = rep(c(1,3,2,5),5), x = round(rexp(20), digits=2), y = round(runif(20), digits=2))
d2 = data.frame(id = rep(c(1,4,3,2),5), x = round(rexp(20), digits=2), y = round(runif(20), digits=2))
```

Is there is a simple way of doing this in `R` rather than having to load each data set, sort it by `id` and write it using write.table?

Comment: What is the question? `write.table` doesn't work?

Comment: The question is how to do this in R.

Comment: I am asking for a simple way to do this rather than loading 100 data sets at a time

Comment: Look into R way of looping - [apply](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/). Loop through your directory read one file at a time, sort it and write it out. You will need combination of following functions `?apply`,`?list.files`, `?read.table`, `?write.table`.

Comment: I am a beginner, I don't know how to apply those functions. I was reading but it is taking me long to figure out each and I need to do this soon.

Comment: Are these `.dat` files in text format or in R format?

Comment: They are in text format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lapply(list.files(), #get list of files
       function(myfile){
         df <- read.table(myfile, header=TRUE) #read the file
         dfsorted <- df[ order(df$id),] #sort the file
         write.table(dfsorted, paste("sorted",myfile,sep="_")) #write out the sorted file
       })
```

I didn't test the code, but should work with bit of tinkering.

Comment: I tried: I get the following error message: Error: unexpected '{' in:
"lapply(list.files(),
funciton(myfile){

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. I replaced `ID` with `id` and adjust the last line as: 
`write.table(dfsorted, file = paste("a",myfile,sep="_"), row.names=FALSE, sep = "\t", quote=FALSE )`
to get the correct file extension.

Comment: I also added the missing `)` at the end.